# Is it possible to look at the source code in a .m file in a framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm trying to work on a problem I'm having with Open Feint and would like to see the code in a method I'm calling. When I jump to definition Xcode just brings me to the header file. Is there anyway I can open the framework up and have a gander at the .m file?

I would like to know if this is possible in general, but also in particular for Open Feint.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, no. Frameworks ship with compiled code, not with the source files. (You can jump into the code with a debugger, but you'll only see the assembly code.) Of course, if the framework is open source, you can download the code and look at it that way.